# Do D&D 5E characters get the characteristics of both Classes AND Backgrounds?

Tags: dnd-5e, cleric, background

I went into character creation assuming yes, but I feel like I'm overdoing it.
If I'm doing this right, my Half-Elf Cleric (Nature) with Acolyte Background has:

- **Two** Holy Symbols (from Cleric and Acolyte)
- Proficiency in **seven** skills.
- Fluency in **five** languages.

I'm just going with my gut here, but something doesn't feel right. When I designed a Tiefling Warlock a while back, I only had two languages and 4 skill proficiencies.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't seem to be doing anything wrong whatsoever.  I have a Rogue who just joined my campaign who has **Seven** proficiencies as well AND he has a passive Wis and Int score of 21 and 22 ...he see's everything....automatically....and he did so by following the rules.  You gain Background, Racial, AND Class proficiencies and abilities as long as you meet whatever requirements they have if any.  (I think you only need *one* holy symbol however....though a spare never hurt, right?)

If you go to page 11 in the PHB (Players Hand Book) where it talks about 'Building Bruenor' and read from there, it will lay out the steps and also mention that you record bonuses from both your race/class and your Background.

> **Choose a Race** : pg11 PHB *"...Your character's race grants particular racial traits, such as special senses, proficiency with weapons/tools/ or one or more skills...."*
>
> **Choose a Class** : pg11 PHB *"...You receive a number of benefits from your class....proficiencies in armor, weapons, skills, saving throws, and sometimes tools..."*
>
> **Choose a Background** :pg14 PHB (top left) *"...gives your character a background feature....and proficiency in two skills, and potentially additional languages and/or tools..."*